# Is "display" an initial-stress-derived noun?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm trying to find out if "display" is an initial-stress-derived noun, i.e. if it is pronounced with emphasis on the first syllable when used as noun and on the second syllable when used as verb.

It is not on the [list on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun#List), but the list claims to be incomplete. Wikipedia also claims that the list of affected words differs from area to area.

I pronounce it as initial-stress-derived noun, but have been corrected a couple of times by one other non-native speaker, who claims that it is always pronounced with emphasis on the second syllable. Who is right?

Comment: I have never heard the noun pronounced with initial stress.

Comment: I know a Louisiana-born cajun in his 70s who pronounces the noun “display” with initial stress, but the reason that that caught my ear is that it’s unusual.

Comment: As a Texan, I have heard this, as well... but, as @TylerJamesYoung said, it's not the norm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pronunciations can be regional, so I'm cautious about being dogmatic on such a question. But as an American who has lived in the northeast and the Midwest, I have never heard "display" pronounced with accent on the first syllable.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on Jay's answer:

Two years ago, my own answer would have been the same as Jay's: I have spent most in my life in Florida and had never heard "display" with an emphasis on the first syllable.

But, adding to some other comments above, I've spent the last year or so in North Carolina, and now I *have* met several people who do pronounce "display" with emphasis on the first syllable. This includes a professor who is originally from Texas, as well as a fellow student who is originally from North Carolina.

Indeed, it seems to be a regional thing.

Answer (score 1):

In English, **dɪsˈpleɪ** is the correct pronunciation.
But Display is also a German word, where both **ˈdɪsplɛɪ̯** and **dɪsˈplɛɪ̯** are used. It's common for non-native speakers that their German use of **ˈdɪsplɛɪ̯** slips into their English.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard it pronounced both ways -- usually when it is pronounced with initial-stress it is referring to the noun (like a computer screen), whereas the second syllable is stressed when referring to the verb, "to display".  Definitely seems to be a regional thing.